# VBA Macros Get E-Mail addresses from specific cells and generate an email to all of them

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the following table, with email addresses in specific cells:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to generate an email to all of them, but unfortunately I managed to send it only to one of all:

[image]

Here are my ideas, which are obviously not working :(

```
'emailItem.to = Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 12).Value

'emailItem.to = Worksheets("Sheet14").Range("H2:H2, L2:L2, P2:P2, T2:T2") NOT WORKING
```

Do you have any other ideas? I do not want to put them in CC or BCC..

Comment: For a small list of 4 cells, it's enough to just write it as 4 commands.

Comment: This is not working.. It takes the last command:

emailItem.to = Worksheets("Sheet16").Range("H2:H2").Value
emailItem.to = Worksheets("Sheet16").Range("L2:L2").Value

Comment: You'll need to concatenate the 4 cells with appropriate separator inbetween.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
Contact = Worksheets("Sheet16").Cells(2,8).Value
Contact1 = Worksheets("Sheet16").Cells(2,12).Value
Contact2 = Worksheets("Sheet16").Cells(2,16).Value
Contact3 = Worksheets("Sheet16").Cells(2,20).Value

' We build the emails below
Worksheets("Sheet16").Cells(12,1).Value = Contact & ";" & Contact1 & ";" & Contact2 & ";" & Contact3
```

Comment: I added ; and it worked! Thanks